# Validating a BinData::Record on initialization

Tags: ruby, bindata

Is there a way to validate the fields being set on a BinData::Record during initialization?  The check_value for each parameter appears to only be evaluated after reading from an input stream

```
class Foo < BinData::Record
   uint8 :bar,:check_value=>lambda{raise 'Here is an error'}
end

Foo.new(:bar=>5)  #Does not raise validation exception
```

I've tried adding an 'initialize_instance' where it does a read on 'to_binary_s' but it throws some other errors, presumably because the object isn't fully instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `def initialize` method. Then put the validation inside it. 
The initialize is run on object instantiation, so the check must occur.

Comment: Sorry, its not as simple as that.  The library checks to see if an initialize method has been written and takes other actions

Comment: you can't override initialize with bindata records, they recommend creating a method `initialize_instance` instead.